# Android Broadcast Receiver for Sent SMS messages?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I created a `BroadcastReceiver` and configured it with an `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` action filter so it is called everytime the phone *receives* a text.

Is there some event/action or other way for my application to be notified whenever the phone *sends* a text (preferably independent of the application that sends it)?

So far the only option I see is to poll the content provider for `content://sms/sent` which doesn't even give me all sent texts because applications can choose not to put it there.

Comment: As the API for sending SMS messages (android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager) allows developers to specify custom intents to be broadcasted when sending succeeds or fails, I don't think it's possible to listen for a single "sms message sent" intent.

Comment: Hi Josef, I am wondering have tou made any more advances with this? I can currently listen out for messages being sent via a content observer but I would like to stop the sms from being sent over the GSM/CDMA network and sent over a data connection instead. Would you have any insight into how to block an sms from sending over GSM/CDMA?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately there is (currently) no way to implement a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) because the standard sms application uses a [`SmsManger`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html) to send the messages but specifies concrete internal classes for the sent and delivered intents (`SmsReceiver.class` and `MessageStatusReceiver.class` respectively). Not that it is any consolation but you can find the following comment in the Sms application's [source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Mms.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/com/android/mms/transaction/SmsMessageSender.java;hb=HEAD):

```
// TODO: Fix: It should not be necessary to
// specify the class in this intent.  Doing that
// unnecessarily limits customizability.
```

The best alternative seems to be polling `content://sms/sent`, potentially using a [`ContentObserver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html).

Comment: Hi Josef, 

I am wondering have tou made any more advances with this? I can currently listen out for messages being sent via a content observer but I would like to stop the sms from being sent over the GSM/CDMA network and sent over a data connection instead. Would you have any insight into how to block an sms from sending over GSM/CDMA?

Comment: No, unfortunately. But I think *blocking* the message is going to be even trickier. I'll let you know if I think of something. Meanwhile, try asking a question on stackoverflow.com ;-)

Comment: Of course a ContentObserver only plays nicely with those applications that actually use the SMS/MMS content store. Which some messaging apps (and all malicious apps) don't do.