# Android SMS MMS outgoing count in 1.5

Tags: android

Can anyone help me with the coding to get the outgoing SMS / MMS count in Android 1.5?

I would like to my code to know automatically when the SMS or MSS will be sent from the phone.

Comment: Wait... so are you wanting the count of sent messages, or just to know when a message is sent?

Comment: hi thanks for the response,  if i can able to get the outgoing sms / MMS  count means that is better for me . else you can able to trigger my apps when the SMS/MMS sent out from mobile that's  another one good option , so if anything means it help full for me  am using SDK 1. 5 
please help me

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is currently no good way to trigger custom code when the phone sends a message. If you only need the count of sent messages you can query the content provider for `content://sms/sent` but that only gives you messages that were sent by an application that stores them there after sending (e.g. Android Messaging Application).

Related questions

- [Android Broadcast Receiver for Sent SMS messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990558/android-broadcast-receiver-for-sent-sms-messages)
- [How to register for SMS database changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285720/how-to-register-for-sms-database-changes)

Comment: Hi , from that link i can not able get the codes its broken link can you say how can please thank you