# Android: Sending a Mail/SMS/Tweet with Intent.ACTION_SEND / requestCode / resultCode?

Tags: android, sendmail, sendmessage

I'm using the following code :

```
Intent sendMailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        sendMailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.Share_Mail_Subject));
        sendMailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.Share_Mail_Text)); 
        sendMailIntent.setType("text/plain");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendMailIntent, "Email / SMS / Tweet ?"));
```

Then I would like to be able to make the difference between:
1. my user has indeed sent en email/SMS ... OR
2. my user has in fact pushed the BACK BUTTON ... and didn't send anything.

Is there a way to make this difference ?

=> Should I launch the activity with startActivityForResult ? and catch the requestCode/resultCode with onActivityResult ...

=> What king of resultCode should I expect ? how to grab it correctly ? Where should I put these lines of code ? Any snippet of code would be very helpful here.

thanks in advance.

Hub

Answer (score 1):

I realize it has been quite a while since you asked this question and Android has changed quite a bit during this time. I'm not sure if you are still looking for an answer, but if you are, you can do this with the new `Intent.createChooser()` method, which takes a third `PendingIntent.getIntentSender()` argument, and a `BroadcastReceiver`. Here's how you do it:

```
Intent sendMailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendMailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.Share_Mail_Subject));
sendMailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.Share_Mail_Text)); 
sendMailIntent.setType("text/plain");

Intent receiver = new Intent(this, BroadcastTest.class);
receiver.putExtra("test", "test");

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "test", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
startActivity(chooser);
```

Note that the target for my `receiver` intent was the `BroadcastTest` class which extends `BroadcastReceiver`. When the user chooses an application from the chooser, the `onReceive` method in `BroadcastTest` will be called and if the user presses back, `onReceive` will not be called. This way, you can check whether the user indeed sent an email/sms/tweet or if they pressed back. For example, if this is my `BroadcastTest` class:

```
public class BroadcastTest extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), " " + intent.getExtras().get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

you would get something like `ComponentInfo{org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity}` in your log if the user selected the application Telegram. Using the key `android.intent.extra.CHOSEN_COMPONENT`, you should be able to find what the user picked. Also, don't forget to declare the `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest.

Another way is to use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to make your own chooser. This would allow you to programmatically get the user selection. The method is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495909/how-to-know-which-intent-is-selected-in-intent-action-send) StackOverflow post.

To address your question about `startActivityForResult`, from Android's source, you can see that the `Activity` that chooses among `Intents` doesn't `setResult()` at all. Thus, if you try to catch a result code in `onActivityResult`, it will always be 0 (`RESULT_CANCELED`). Thus, using `startActivityForResult`, you cannot determine whether the user selected an option or pressed back.

Comment: Using a BroadcastReceiver still doesn't help to determine whether or not the message was actually sent

Comment: You should probably see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094666/5746918