# Android Email Intent, anyway to know if the user actually sent the email or not?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am using email Intent to send emails, I need to detect if the user really sent the email or just pressed back(ie discarded email), is there anyway to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is answered very well here [email: Which are Intent.ACTION_SEND return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209649/email-which-are-intent-action-send-return-values)

Basically there is nothing specified, anything can happen.