# way to know if the user has chosen the intent action from chooser or not

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Is there a way to know if the user has chosen the intent action from the chooser or not.

I want to do this - If its chosen by user then finish the current activity else remain in the current activity.

I have this code:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
finish();
```

But this always finishes the current activity irrespective of user chose the email client or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to find out this...

Comment: please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515888/android-email-intent-anyway-to-know-if-the-user-actually-sent-the-email-or-not

Comment: No there isn't a way to determine this...check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600149/get-mail-sent-notification-in-onactivityresult-android?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by showing you own custom chooser

First get all packages which can  process your intent

```
private List<String> getInstalledComponentList(Intent emailIntent)
            throws NameNotFoundException {

        List<ResolveInfo> ril = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
        List<String> componentList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String name = null;

        for (ResolveInfo ri : ril) {
            if (ri.activityInfo != null) {
                Resources res = getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                if (ri.activityInfo.labelRes != 0) {
                    name = res.getString(ri.activityInfo.labelRes);
                } else {
                    name = ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                            getPackageManager()).toString();
                }
                componentList.add(name);
            }
        }
        return componentList;
    }
```

Then show a dialog with all this list of packages [like this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList)

Then process the click event and start the selected package