# How to know which intent is selected in Intent.ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to use Android Intent.ACTION_SEND for quickly sharing something. So I got a sharing list like this:
[image: Sharing intent list]

But I want to share different content for each action, such as:

- If sharing by Email/Gmail, content should be "Share by email".
- If sharing by Facebook, content should be "Share by Facebook".

So, is it possible to do that?

Comment: where is the problem? you send the intent depending on the item clicked?! where is the problem

Comment: ah, I mean how can I know which Intent is selected to perform sharing action?

Comment: so bad, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137592/how-to-know-the-action-choosed-in-a-intent-createchooser and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417019/how-to-get-the-user-selection-from-startactivityforresultintent-createchooserfi, I cannot find what intent user chooses.

Comment: oh my god! I have never used such thing! I thought this is something you created! hehe of course you can't.. How about you try to startActivityForResult and try onActivityResult to read the intent maybe some info is there... But if the community says that you can't then probably this has been already experimented

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't get such information.

Unless you create your own implementation of the dialog for the activity selection.

To create such dialog you need to use `PackageManager` and its `queryIntentActivities()` function. The function returns `List<ResolveInfo>`.

`ResolveInfo` contains some information about an activity (`resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName`), and with the help of `PackageManager` you can get other information (useful for displaying the activity in the dialog) - application icon drawable, application label, ... .

Display the results in a list in a dialog (or in an activity styled as a dialog). When an item is clicked create new Intent.ACTION_SEND, add the content you want and add the package of the selected activity (`intent.setPackage(pkgName)`).

Answer (score 12):

There is not direct method to access such kind of information....

Step 1: Inside your code first of all you need to declare an adapter which will contain your custom view of list to be shared on...

```
//sharing implementation
                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                    // what type of data needs to be send by sharing
                    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

                    // package names
                    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

                    // list package
                    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent, 0);

                    objShareIntentListAdapter = new ShareIntentListAdapter(CouponView.this,activityList.toArray());

                    // Create alert dialog box
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                    builder.setTitle("Share via");
                    builder.setAdapter(objShareIntentListAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                            ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) objShareIntentListAdapter.getItem(item);

                            // if email shared by user
                            if(info.activityInfo.packageName.contains("Email") 
                                    || info.activityInfo.packageName.contains("Gmail")
                                    || info.activityInfo.packageName.contains("Y! Mail")) {

                                PullShare.makeRequestEmail(COUPONID,CouponType);
                            }

                            // start respective activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
                            intent.setType("text/plain");
                            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  ShortDesc+" from "+BusinessName);
                            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ShortDesc+" "+shortURL);
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, ShortDesc+" "+shortURL);                                                            
                            ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);                                              

                        }// end onClick
                    });

                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
```

Step 2: Now you have create a layout inflater for your adapter(ShareIntentListAdapter.java)

```
package com.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ShareIntentListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    private final Activity context; 
    Object[] items;


    public ShareIntentListAdapter(Activity context,Object[] items) {

        super(context, R.layout.social_share, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;

    }// end HomeListViewPrototype

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.social_share, null, true);

        // set share name
        TextView shareName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.shareName);

        // Set share image
        ImageView imageShare = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.shareImage);

        // set native name of App to share
        shareName.setText(((ResolveInfo)items[position]).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString());

        // share native image of the App to share
        imageShare.setImageDrawable(((ResolveInfo)items[position]).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager()));

        return rowView;
    }// end getView

}// end main onCreate
```

Step 3: Create your xml layout type to show list view in dialog box(social_share.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/categoryCell"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shareName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shareImage"
        android:layout_width="35dip"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_view" />

</RelativeLayout>

// vKj
```

Comment: I also recommend changing the alert.show() to be surrounded by an IF to prevent multiple clicks.  if (!alert.isShowing()) { alert.show(); }

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer, but ClickClickClack has an example implementation of how you can intercept the ACTION_SEND intent and choose based off package name and certain characteristics what ends up happening.  In involves most of the steps mentioned by Tomik.

http://clickclickclack.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/intercepting-androids-action_send-intents/

One powerful aspect about this implementation is you can add analytics to your calls.

Comment: this is a brilliant implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Using Tomik great Answer i'm able to produce my own Custom share List using PackageManager
loadLabel and LoadIcon:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

    ArrayList<Drawable> icons;
    ArrayList<String> labels;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        icons=new ArrayList<Drawable>();
        labels=new ArrayList<String>();
        PackageManager manager=getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        List<ResolveInfo> activities=manager.
                queryIntentActivities(intent,0);
        for(int i=0;i<activities.size();i++)
        {
            ApplicationInfo appInfo=null;
            try {
                appInfo=manager.getApplicationInfo(activities.get(i).activityInfo.packageName,0);
                labels.add(name=appInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString()); 
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            icons.add(appInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));
        }
    }

}
```