# android app implement google auto complete activity for 2 inputs

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I have 2 edit text inputs in my app.One is from place and another one  to place.For these 2 inputs I have implemented google auto complete activity but problem when user click on any one of these inputs google autocomplete intent after user place selection completed intent call  onActivityResult().
In onActivityResult() how to know which input clicked.
here is my code

```
    fromPlaceEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {
                        AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS).setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_GEOCODE)
                                .build();
                        Intent intent =
                                new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY).setFilter(typeFilter)
                                        .build(MainActivity.this);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                        // TODO: Handle the error.
                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                        // TODO: Handle the error.
                    }
                }
            });
toPlaceEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS).setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_GEOCODE)
                            .build();
                    Intent intent =
                            new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY).setFilter(typeFilter)
                                    .build(MainActivity.this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                }
            }
        });
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);

                String fullName= (String) place.getAddress();
                #// here I want to know which input clicked and set fullname in input text#
                fromPlaceEdit.setText(fullName);
            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i("fdfdf", status.getStatusMessage());

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The user canceled the operation.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495909/how-to-know-which-intent-is-selected-in-intent-action-send

Comment: Use a different request code when calling startActivityForResult. Don't forget to also change the onActivityResult too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it different way.
I have created two global boolean value each for from place and to place.
then when user click on from place or to place change boolean value of same place then on onActivityResult check which boolean value is true and set result place name to same input box.
Code follows:

```
public boolean fromplaceSlected =false ;
    public boolean toplaceSlected =false;
 fromPlaceEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {
                        AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS).setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_GEOCODE)
                                .build();
                        Intent intent =
                                new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY).setFilter(typeFilter)
                                        .build(MainActivity.this);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                        // TODO: Handle the error.
                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                        // TODO: Handle the error.
                    }
                }
            });
toPlaceEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS).setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_GEOCODE)
                            .build();
                    Intent intent =
                            new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY).setFilter(typeFilter)
                                    .build(MainActivity.this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                }
            }
        });
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("request", String.valueOf(requestCode));
        // Check that the result was from the autocomplete widget.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the user's selected place from the Intent.
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(getContext(), data);

                String fullName = (String) place.getAddress();

                if(fromplaceSlected){
                    Log.e("from place",fullName);
                    fromPlaceEdit.setText(fullName);
                    fromplaceSlected=false;
                    toplaceSlected=false;
                }
                else if(toplaceSlected){
                    Log.e("toplace" ,fullName);
                    toPlaceEdit.setText(fullName);
                    fromplaceSlected=false;
                    toplaceSlected=false;
                }

            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(getContext(), data);
                Log.e("sdsdsdd", "Error: Status = " + status.toString());
                fromplaceSlected=false;
                toplaceSlected=false;
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Indicates that the activity closed before a selection was made. For example if
                // the user pressed the back button.
                fromplaceSlected=false;
                toplaceSlected=false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code may work, but it's a bit hacky. Here is the good way to do it:

```
   public static final int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_FROM_PLACE_REQUEST_CODE=1;
   public static final int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_TO_PLACE_REQUEST_CODE=2;

fromPlaceEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {
                      //Do your stuff from place
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_FROM_PLACE_REQUEST_CODE);

                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                        // TODO: Handle the error.
                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                        // TODO: Handle the error.
                    }
                }
            });
toPlaceEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                   //Do your stuff to place
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_TO_PLACE_REQUEST_CODE);

                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                }
            }
        });
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_FROM_PLACE_REQUEST_CODE) {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              //Do your ok >from place< stuff here
           } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
              //Handle your error >from place<
           } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
               // The user canceled the operation.
           }
       } else if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_TO_PLACE_REQUEST_CODE) {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              //Do your ok >to place< stuff here
           } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
              //Handle your error >to place<
           } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
               // The user canceled the operation.
           }
        }
    }
```

From documentation: 
  [requestCode  int: If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))