# Get app package name selected by user for sharing using 'Intent.ACTION_SEND'

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-broadcastreceiver

I am using following code to share text

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "share test");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
```

I want to know package name of the app chosen by user to share.
I have tried doing it using **IntentSender** for 5.1+ devices using following code

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "share test");
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

Intent receiver = new Intent(this, BroadcastTest.class);
receiver.putExtra("test", "test");

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
startActivity(chooser);
```

Following is the BroadcastReceiver

```
public class BroadcastTest extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), " " + intent.getExtras().get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

Referred this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38342788/6053724 but onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver is not getting invoked.
Is there anything that I am missing to get it worked?

**Update:** Found out that above code works well on 5.1(api 22) but on 6.0(api 23) broadcast is not received immediately on picking up app for sharing or sometimes broadcast is lost.

Comment: Did you register that `BroadcastReceiver` somewhere, via `registerReceiver()` or the manifest?

Comment: Yes. I have added it manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but there's a lib which might help you with this: https://github.com/zawadz88/material-activity-chooser

It allows you to e.g. handle the clicked app (see https://github.com/zawadz88/material-activity-chooser/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/zawadz88/sample/TrackingActivityChooserActivity.java)

Comment: Thanks @piotr . But I am not allowed to use any library or custom UI for chooser.