# get post event from share dialog

Tags: android, share, social-networking

Hi I have functionality in my app where I have to do some code on event when user shares my app.
So basically on tap share icon androids default share indent will open which will show installed apps through which user can share(e.g whatsapp, Facebook, gmail) then user will select any of the above app and then once he shares app i need that event of sharing post.
Please help me to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to activate "Share" button in android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167701/how-to-activate-share-button-in-android-app)

Comment: No i need event that user has successfully shared message

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391497/get-app-package-name-selected-by-user-for-sharing-using-intent-action-send