# Disble SMS Programmatically Android

Tags: android, text, sms, contacts

I'm developing an app where the user selects contacts from his/her address book and then the app prevents them from texting said people. My problem is that I can't find any code to prevent texting people. I've found apps that prevent you from calling certain contacts but I'm more focused on texting. Any help would be appreciated. 
-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible for reasons specified at [Android Broadcast Receiver for Sent SMS messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990558/android-broadcast-receiver-for-sent-sms-messages)

It seems that no Broadcast is made for outgoing SMS, so unlike calls, you can't adjust the content (number) or prevent it completely.