# SMS sent/delivery status from Default Message App - Android

Tags: android, sms, sendmessage, telephony, smsmanager

I am able to get the send / receive SMS status when sent from my android application.
For send using the below code,

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, sentIntent, deliveredIntent);
```

Where , `sentIntent` and `deliveredIntent` are Pending intents

I can get the SMS sent/delivery report successfully (When send from my application).

But, When I send SMS by using default Message application, the BroadcastReceiver not get called.

I have added the below filter for my BroadcastReceiver class

```
 <receiver android:name=".SMSBReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SEND_SMS" />
 </receiver>
```

Comment: Do you have set the SMS permission? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>`

Comment: Yes, I am able to send the SMS from my application. I want to get send response if I use default message app for send SMS

Comment: Also get the sms delivery status ,if I sent from my application. Then, how can I get default message app SMS delivery report.

Comment: You can't, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990558/android-broadcast-receiver-for-sent-sms-messages

Answer (score 0):

You can't get sent status from your app, if the sms is sent from Default SMS app. Because the receiver in delivery PendingIntent will not be the one you added, instead it's of Default SMS app.